# Variables called from a file in HTML

Tags: html, file, variables, config

I am trying to code my website so that it reads variables from a text file and I can reference then whenever I want on the webpage.
In a perfect world it would be the code below

```
LoadVariable example('examplefile.txt')
<p>This story is called #example#</p>
```

I'd have a bunch of these so I wouldn't have to go in and edit the code every time I need something to change.

I would settle for the html file calling some code, like an external small snippet of code it can call.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use AngularJS

For Example:

```
<p>this story is named {{story}}</p>
```